Multiple object files with identical T(ext) symbols in GCC on Mac aarch64
I have a very simple project on my Mac (architecture = aarch64, xnu-10063.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64).
It consists of the following:
// main.cpp

#include "s1.hpp"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    auto p = std::source_location::current();
    std::cout << "Function: " << p.function_name() << " -- " << p.file_name()
              << ":" << p.line() << '\n';

    std::cout << "Calling f()\n";

    f1();
    f2();

    return 0;
}

// src/s1.cpp

#include "s1.hpp"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

void f1()
{
    auto p = std::source_location::current();
    std::cout << "Function: " << p.function_name() << " -- " << p.file_name()
              << ":" << p.line() << '\n';
}

void f2()
{
    auto p = std::source_location::current();
    std::cout << "Function: " << p.function_name() << " -- " << p.file_name()
              << ":" << p.line() << '\n';
}

// src/s1.hpp

#pragma once

void f1();
void f2();

And building with this CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.0)
project(source_loc_test 
    VERSION 0.1.0
    LANGUAGES CXX C
)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Boost 1.84 REQUIRED)

add_executable(source_loc_test
    main.cpp
    src/s1.cpp
)

target_include_directories(source_loc_test PRIVATE
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    src
)

Building this with clang (Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)), everything works. Source locations are printed as expected. However, building with gcc (tried with 11.4, 13.1 and 14.1) downloaded via brew install gcc I get a segmentation fault:
Function: int main() -- /Users/me/cpp/source_loc_test/main.cpp:8
Calling s1::f()
Function: int main() -- /Users/me/cpp/source_loc_test/main.cpp:8
[1]    34058 segmentation fault  /Users/ssh_user/cpp/prj/source_loc_test/build/source_loc_test

Note how the location from main.cpp is printed in the call in s1.cpp. It is as if it uses the same source_location::current() object as in main.cpp.
Debugging the gcc build, I can see that the source_location::current().function_name() and friends (.file_name(), etc.) has some pointers that are invalid (all are 0x000000001) in the s1.cpp file.
Looking at the object files I see the following:
❯ nm -S -C src/s1.cpp.o | grep source_lo
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/nm: warning: sizes with --print-size for Mach-O files are always zero.
0000000000000138 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::function_name() const
00000000000000e6 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::line() const
000000000000010e 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::file_name() const

❯ nm -S -C main.cpp.o | grep source_lo
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/nm: warning: sizes with --print-size for Mach-O files are always zero.
0000000000000138 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::function_name() const
00000000000000e6 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::line() const
000000000000010e 0000000000000000 T std::source_location::file_name() const

First of all, I cannot understand how they can both have the T symbol and the linker still does not complain. Second, I also see this when compiling with clang, which seems to work without problem.
When compiling the exact same program on Linux (with gcc as well), I get the W (weak) symbol as I would expect from a consteval (implicit inline) function, so I wonder why there is a discrepancy between gcc for Mac and Linux here.
Lastly, I noticed that when removing #include <boost/asio.hpp> in one of the functions, everything seems to be working again. Again - this is only necessary when compiling on Mac with gcc. I wonder if this only triggers it as a side-effect because of a different memory layout or this is the actual cause (even compiling without asio, I still get the T symbol for source_location).
I'm really at my wits end here.

Am I doing something that is out of the standard?
AM I using boost in the wrong way?
Why is multiple identical symbols allowed by the linker?

Update
No luck using otool for printing symbols:
❯ otool -TV src/s1.cpp.o
src/s1.cpp.o:
Table of contents (0 entries)
module name      symbol name

Request:
Can anyone repro on a ARM based Mac? It would be really nice to have confirmed that this is not some quirk in my environment.

Where is s1 defined? nm is not a native macOS Mach-O tool. I would use otool.

I don't have a clue and I cannot repro on any linux config. I do note though that your example is inconsistent (sometimes it uses s1:: namespace). I assume that's just copy/paste error, but maybe it's a symptom

You didn't mention the clang version. Recalled clang adapted source_location in recent versions. Maybe it's related?

The duplicate symbols are presumably inline functions which the linker is quite able to deal with

@LouisGo, It works fine on clang, so I would be very surprised if it was related to that. I added the clang version in the question.

@sehe, Correct - I originally used the s1 namespace, since I at first thought this could be some namespace related issue not playing nice with source_location, but found that it failed without any namespaces as well. Updated the question to reflect this.
@273K, see this comment.

@AlanBirtles, Aren't inline functions normally marked as weak in the object files?

@273K, I'll try out with otool to see if that gives more insight.

@SupAl can you get it working on goldbolt? I tried this but CMAKE cannot work. I am not a cmake expert... Maybe that would help.

@LouisGo, I'll give it a try. It would be very nice to reproduce it there, but I'm not sure if we can get it to compile / run on a Mac.

I got it to build here https://godbolt.org/z/Tsx1rj6b5, but I think it's cross-compiling, so it cannot run on the machine :( .
You can see that CMake uses this compiler:
Check for working CXX compiler:  /opt/compiler-explorer/arm64/gcc-13.1.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++ 
